# Matrix array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I have a program that should read in an integer value `x` from the console, and then print out a multi dimensional. The value of the row `i` on column `j` should be `i *j`. For example: if I input `3`, the matrix should look like this:

```
1  2  3  

2  4  6  

3  6  9
```

Now, I have written this code in my Main function:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Input a value: ");
        int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[,] arr = new int[x,x];

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
            {
                arr[i, j] = arr[i, j] + arr[i, j];

                Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");        
            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

So, when I input `3` from my code, I get the output:

```
0 0 0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `i--` should be `i++`

Comment: Step through it with a debugger, and the mistake should be obvious.

Comment: I tried that, but then I got the output to be: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 in just one row

Comment: put a line break in outerloop, after the inner loop end, like Console.WriteLine("\n"); and change to arr[i,j] =i*j;

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to change `i--` to `i++`.
2. Put `Console.WriteLine()` after inner `for` loop. It will print a line break after every `x` numbers to make it loop like matrix.
3. You're saying *The value of the row `i` on column `j` should be `i *j`*, but I can't see any `i * j` in your code. Change your calculations to that: `arr[i, j] = i * j;`.

That should be it, but because your loops run from `0` to `x - 1` and you want result to be as if it was from `1` to `x` you have to adapt your calculations and make it `arr[i, j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);`.

Complete code should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("Input a value: ");
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int[,] arr = new int[x, x];

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
        arr[i, j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);

        Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You´re saing that the value of arr[i, j] must be equals to i * j, but you´re not doing it on your code.

change

```
arr[i, j] = arr[i, j] + arr[i, j];
```

to

```
arr[i, j] = (i+1) * (j+1);
```

another thing that you need to change is that i are being decremented on the for loop, because of this code: **i--**. change it to **i++**

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how the int[,] is full of zero's all your doing is adding zero + zero.

Seems like what you really want is this:

```
    int[,] arr = new int[x,x];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            arr[i, j] = (i+1) * (j + 1);

            Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");        
        }
        Console.Write("\r\n");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: this produces the same output as what you wanted in your question.